# Salesforce - Flexcard with SOQL Data source - Error - Invalid Descriptor Format: markup://c:should-intercept-webauthn[COMPONENT]

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud, omnis-studio-10

I am recently trying my hands on Omnistudio. I have created a flexcard with Data Source as SOQL and provided below Query:

```
SELECT Id, WorkOrderNumber FROM Workorder
```

However, When I click design without adding any build component. I get below error:

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Invalid Descriptor Format: markup://c:should-intercept-webauthn[COMPONENT] [Invalid Descriptor Format: markup://c:should-intercept-webauthn[COMPONENT]] Failing descriptor: {markup://c:should-intercept-webauthn}
```

Could someone please help me with resolving the issue. I would like to use table to eventually display the list on experience cloud site.